# OpenCV 2.4.0 vs 2.3.1 + ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-fuerte, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm facing problems with ROS and OpenCV, I have my stuffs developed in 2.3.1 and ROS is comming with opencv 2.4.0, and I'm also facing problem in RGBDSLAM.

My questions:

**Should i update everything to 2.4.0?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33543/opencv-2.4.0-vs-2.3.1-+-ros-fuerte/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS doesn't come with OpenCV. OpenCV is an external library. Having said that, most of the packages have been developed with 2.3.1. I suggest installing 2.4 and submitting tickets to packages that don't compile.

Also, it is preferred to ask only one question per posting so we can close the question when it is answered. You asked 4 questions.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1